# Automated way to release Unused Elastic IPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Please Suggest any way or script to release unused ec2 elastic ips. I tried with boto and aws-cli but i'm unable to complete it. Any one could help . i thought of `aws ec2 release-address --public-ip <x.x.x.x>` but I'm thinking how can i loop this by sending unused elastic ips.

Thanks

Comment: what is your primary goal?  to release these IPs or to have a script?  if just releasing them is the goal, why not use the web console?

Comment: @Skaperen ... yeah thanks.. I  need to release unused ips through script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a better way but I've just tested this one and it works well

Note: If you use EC2 classic you can use the `aws ec2 release-address --public-ip <x.x.x.x>` command to release elastic IP otherwise you must use `aws ec2 release-address --allocation-id`

**EC2-Classic**

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --query 'Addresses[].[PublicIp,AssociationId]' --output text | \
awk '$2 == "None" { print $1 }' | \
xargs -I {} aws ec2 release-address --public-ip {}
```

**EC2-VPC**

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --query 'Addresses[].[AllocationId,AssociationId]' --output text | \
awk '$2 == "None" { print $1 }' | \
xargs -I {} aws ec2 release-address --allocation-id {}
```

What those commands are doing:

- List all ElasticIP information and query only the `AssociationId` field along with either the `PublicIp` or `AllocationId`
- Keep only the records where the `AssociationId` field is `None` and print either the `PublicIp` or `AllocationId` value
- Pass this value to the `release-address` command to actually release it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.